# Character to show cut off file paths

Tags: design, cli

I have a cli application, that has the option of displaying file paths in addition to typical output. Some file paths can be quite long so I want to cut the path off once it is longer than a certain amount of characters.

Traditionally cut off sentences would be cut off with an ellipsis `...`, however using three dots would shorten the path even more. There is the unicode ellipsis character `…`, but this wouldn't work if the terminal didn't support `utf8`. Is there a character that is traditionally used in this situation that would be easy for the user to recognize?

Comment: Yes, the three character ellipsis. It does shorten the path more, but it's a compromise between fitting as many characters as possible on the display and using a well-recognised symbol to denote truncation. Also, it's normally a good idea to apply the `...` before the end of the path (so eg the last 10 characters are shown after the `...`) as that makes the path clearer (avoids 10s/100s lines all with the same text as the filename is obscured).

Comment: @DavidArno: Respectfully, I *hate* the broken paths created by an ellipsis in the middle of them.  There's absolutely nothing you can do with them (copy/pasting is useless), and they only hint at the actual file location, so why bother?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you are entitled to hate them :) In the OP's case, they would suffer as you say, as he will be printing them to a console/shell. However, in a GUI, I'd expect the full path to be both shown as a tooltip on mouse-over and on copy.

Comment: If it's a cli application,  don't cut them off. My terminal window might be huge compared to yours. If it's wrapping I'll pipe to a file then open it in vim.

Comment: @DavidArno Well yes, but specifically the application is designed to look well on 80 character width terminals, and paths only get a subsection of that so those three characters is actually a lot.

Comment: @whatsisname File names aren't the only thing being displayed on the line or column, and I want o support 80 width terminals.